# problem displaying data in a dropdown using ejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I have a profile page which displays a gender dropdown for the user to select the gender. When I select the gender and update the profile the data is successfully saved to MongoDB.

The problem is that whenever I go to edit the profile page, the first value from options is displayed although the profile data is returned to the page I am not sure how I can display the selected value from the database in the ejs template. Following is the code for my template drop-down:

```
< div class="input-field col s6">
  < select name="gender">
    < option value="--Select--" disabled> Choose your gender
    < /option>< option value="0"> Female< /option>
    < option value="1"> Male< /option>
  < /select>
  < label> Select Gender
  < /label>
< /div>
```

My get profile code:

```
router.get('/profile/:member_id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {

  Profile.findOne({
      member_id: req.params.member_id
    })
    .then(profile => {

      if (req.params.member_id != req.user.member_id) {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Your are not authorized to update this profile.');
        res.redirect('/user/userdashboard/1');
      } else {
        res.render('user/profile', {
          profile: profile
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('could not find user profile');
    });

});
```

How can I display the value returned from my database as the already selected option in the dropdown inside my ejs template?

Answer (score 0):

In your dropdown HTML, you can toggle the appropriate `<option>` tag's `selected` attribute:

```
<select name="gender">
  <option value="--Select--" disabled>Choose your gender</option>
  <option selected=<%= profile.gender === "Female" %> value="0">Female</option>
  <option selected=<%= profile.gender === "Male" %> value="1">Male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The above code doesn't select the value which was in the db. I used a ternary condition to get the job done:

<option <% profile.gender===0 ? "selected" : "" %> value="0">Female</option>
                                <option <% profile.gender===1 ? "selected" : "" %> value="1">Male</option>

Comment: Sorry...the code is as follows:

`<option <%- profile.gender==0 ? "selected" : "" %> value="0">Female</option>
                                <option <%- profile.gender==1 ? "selected" : "" %> value="1">Male</option>`